# Abstract Algebra: Automorphism and irreducible

Tags: self-learning, irreducible-polynomials, automorphic-forms

I done how to prove this the question is

A. Show that there is an automorphism of the ring of rational number $\mathbb{Q}(i)[x] $that has order of $4$.

I suppose i can say that if $\varphi$ is an automorphism, then $\varphi(x)=x$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $\varphi(x)$ is a polynomial of degree one, say $mx+n$. If we consider what gets sent to $x$ by $\varphi$, we see that $m$ must be a unit of $\mathbb{Q}$, so $m=\pm 1$. I don't know I am right? If I am right how to continue to prove that it has order of $4$.

B. I have to show whether the following expression is reducible or not

> $x^{42}+42x+4x^2+42$ over rational number $\mathbb{Q}$[x]

In this can I substitute any random rational numbers to prove that it is reducible or not?

Comment: I have updated my question A.

Comment: $m \in {\mathbb Q}(i)$ for the first question.

Answer (score 1):

A: Hint: Can you find an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ of order 4?

B: Consider using $p = 2$ with Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Apologies I have updated my question B. I know i can prove via Eisenstein's Criteria but I am confused how to prove for this expression. And for question A that is question how can I find and show there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$(i) of order 4